# The relation between being analytic on an interval and being equal to a taylor series on that interval.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm in my first semester of mathematics, and have noticed that some professors seem to use a function's "being analytical" and "being equal to the taylor series of a certain point a" on an interval interchangeably.
Now, the definition of being analytical is that a function f is *locally* equal to its Taylor Series for every point in I. When looking at other questions, I was able to ascertain that apparently if f(x)= $\sum_{i=0}^\infty bi(x-a)^i$ on a certain interval D then f is analytical on D. However, I don't know why and I don't know whether the reciprocal is true. I have the suspicion that it isn't, but I figured you could say that if f is analytical on I, you could apply the Heine-Borel-theorem to extract a finite number of points zn, which are all equal to the Taylor Series of that particular point in a certain open interval B(zn,Rn), where the different B(zn,Rn) cover I. Since the open intervalls interlap, you could try to show that the series must be equal since they are equal where they overlap.
But I haven't seen a satisfactory answer and the people I've spoken to don't seem to know either.

Answer (score 2):

The word you want is "analytic", not "analytical".  "Analytical" is sometimes used as a synonym for "closed form", but that's something completely different.

Yes, $f$ is analytic on a set $S$ if it is locally equal to the sum of a convergent Taylor series at every point of $S$.  But there is no guarantee that there is a single Taylor series that converges everywhere on $S$.

For example, you might consider 
$ f(z) = \frac{1}{1+z^2}$ on $[-2,2]$.  Since this has poles at $\pm i$, the radius of convergence of the Taylor series at any point $a$ is the minimum of the distances from $a$ to $\pm i$, and this is always less than the maximum of the distances to $\pm 2$.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I haven't done complex analysis yet but I see what you mean. Do you know any proofs?